# How can I create a shared AppBar in a C# windows store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I've got a windows store app developed in C#
In it I've got a several pages and the navigation between them is done via a Page.TopAppBar
I can't find a way to create a shared version of this bar so I am forced to have copies of the xaml and relevant code behind in all my pages.

The only thing I could think of is to dynamically create it using code behind, which I could call from each page, but I'd rather keep the simplicity of authoring in Xaml if possible and in any case a quick attempt failed to work, looks like Page.TopAppBarProperty is read-only and cannot be set from code-behind

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this trick will help you:

[AppBar Trick](http://silverlightguy.com/2012/03/20/windows-8-metro-application-appbar-trick/)

Here is a sample how to modify AppBar from code behind:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
            rootPage =  e.Parameter as MainPage;
            bottomAppBarPnl = rootPage.FindName("bottomAppBar") as StackPanel;

            if(bottomAppBarPnl != null)
            {               
             // Create the button to add             
             newCust = new Button();               
             newCust.Content = "New Customer";              
             newCust.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(newCust_Click);               
            // Add the button to the AppBar               
            bottomAppBarPnl.Children.Add(newCust);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, that direction moves me forward - as I want my AppBar to be reused across pages I put this logic in the App class, which meant I needed to pass in the button event handler from the calling page. not great but does the job.